# Android XML error for custom view: The following classes could not be found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view as follows:

```
public class TextView2 extends AppCompatTextView
{

public TextView2(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public TextView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}
}
```

and then I want to use it in my layout file:

```
<packagename.TextView2
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

and Android Studio shhows an error:

```
The following classes could not be found:
packagename.TextView2 (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
Tip: Try to build the project.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

but re-building and refreshing did not solve the issue. what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

**packagename** should be package name of your custom class.(Package in which you have created your file)

Suppose you package name is **com.sample.yourapp**
then you should use **com.sample.yourapp.TextView2**

Comment: yes. I'm using the correct package name which is replaced with `packagename` in this question

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the complete name space of your module/app as defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Instead of

```
<packagename.TextView2
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Try using

```
 <com.name1.name2.packagename.TextView2
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```